# Barcode scanning using QuaggaJS in Vaadin

Tags: barcode-scanner, vaadin-flow, quaggajs

I am developing a web application using Vaadin 14.
This application will be used on mobile devices and will be able to barcode scanning from the device camera.
I found a [solution](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/barcode-scanner/overview) that includes [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) for this. However, this solution does not provide access to both cameras of the device.

Should I look for a separate solution to switch between the cameras of the device or is it possible to achieve this with QuaggaJS?

Comment: did you find anything? is this possible?